# Is it allowed to overload operator+ for a standard library type and a built-in type?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, user-defined-types

Is it allowed to overload operators, such as `operator+` for a combination of a standard library type and a built-in type, when such an overload doesn't exist?

For example, is it legal to implement the following operator in the default namespace or a user-defined namespace:

```
std::string operator+(const std::string& s, int right) { ... }
```

I know there are various restrictions about implementing things *in* the `std::` namespace, but it isn't clear to me if there is any rule against the above (whether it's a good idea is of course an entirely different matter!).

Comment: I *think* the answer is “no” and at least one of the types must be user-defined, but I can’t find the reference for that now.

Comment: @Daniel std::string is a user-defined type. The user in this case is people that implemented std::string in the standard library.

Comment: @NeilButterworth It’s defined by the implementation (which includes the standard library). I don’t think “user-defined type” is a defined term in the standard, but if it is and it includes implementation-defined types, then I’m wrong about the term.

Comment: The term isn't [consistently defined](http://www.slashslash.info/2014/01/what-is-a-user-defined-type/). In fact there was a proposal to clarify this (I can't find it at the moment), but it hasn't yet been accepted.

Comment: @DanielH One of the types must be a class type or an enum (or reference to class or enum), there's no user-defined restriction.

Comment: Yes, my thought was wrong. That’s why I made it a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: You can only **override** virtual functions of a base class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For example, is it legal to implement the following operator in the default namespace or a user-defined namespace:
>
> ```
> std::string operator+(const std::string& s, int right) { ... }
> ```

Yes, it's perfectly legal to do this. The only restrictions are about adding names to `namespace std` or specializing member function function templates or class templates or adding deduction guides for class templates in `std`.

There's nothing that stops you from writing something like:

```
namespace N {
    std::string operator+(std::string s, int ) { return s; }
}
```

That is a well-formed program, per the standard. However note that since by definition your operators will not have any program-defined types in them, they will never be found by ADL. Since they are operators, which typically are found by ADL, this in of itself may be a reason to avoid such a pattern:

```
namespace U {
    auto foo() {
        return "hello"s + 1; // error: name lookup doesn't find our operator
    }

    auto bar() {
        using namespace N;
        return "hello"s + 1; // ok: for some definition of ok
    }
}
```

Comment: std::string_literals is probably an exception from the rule that operators are found by ADL

Comment: @erzya It is not.

Comment: I just don't know a way to introduce ```operator ""s``` into the current scope without a using-declaration or using-directive

Comment: @erzya Those are the two ways to make it available, yes.

Answer (score 3):

It is legal to write that. But it won't necessarily do what you want.

If your goal is to make `some_string + 4` legal C++ code, then its legality will depend on exactly where that expression appears. Operator overloading will use ADL to look up the operator [over.match.oper]/3.2:

> The set of non-member candidates is the result of the unqualified lookup of operator@ in the context of the expression according to the usual rules for name lookup in unqualified function calls (6.4.2) except that all member functions are ignored. However, if no operand has a class type, only those non-member
>   functions in the lookup set that have a first parameter of type T1 or “reference to cv T1 ”, when T1 is an enumeration type, or (if there is a right operand) a second parameter of type T2 or “reference to cv T2”, when T2 is an enumeration type, are candidate functions.

But since your `operator+` is *not* in the same namespace as either argument, ADL lookup will fail. And the list of non-member candidates will not automatically include global functions, there's no chance for it to find the right `operator+`.

So you cannot *effectively* overload an operator like this without opening up the namespace. Which of course is forbidden for `std`.

Comment: Wait, maybe I’m misreading that, but it looks like it’ll work in the same namespace as the overload is declared in. Where are you getting that it ignores global functions?

Comment: Weird, it works for every compiler I threw at it (gcc, clang, MSVC, icc), where the operator was called in the same namespace (the default namespace) as it was declared.

Comment: The reference 6.4.2 is to ADL, but based on the text it looks like it does both non-ADL and ADL lookups, just like for a regular unqualified function call. Especially because otherwise it wouldn’t need to discard member functions, which wouldn’t be found by ADL.

Comment: You're misreading. Nicol never said it ignores global functions?

Comment: @Barry - unless I misunderstood Nicol here, he's saying "it won't work because ADL lookup will fail". It does work fine in practice because the non-ADL lookup works fine. So you can _effectively_ overload operators without opening up the namespace (but you'll have to be aware of what namespace your operator is declared in, of course).

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly OK to overload `operator+` between `std::string` and `int`. The only restriction that the standard places on that is (https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/over.oper#6):

> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function and have at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an enumeration.

There is no restriction on the being able to define them in your namespace for even the types from the standard library.

Comment: C++17 is officially [“under publication”](https://www.iso.org/stage-codes.html#60.00) now, it might be time to use [N4659](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659). Failing that, I’d think you should at least use C++14’s [N4140](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/) for non-version-tagged questions.

Comment: @DanielH, I feel pretty up to date for me when I can use C++11 as the guide since I am still required to use VS2008 at work :)

Comment: GCC 3.3 for me a lot of the time. I'd kill for some of that C++11 goodness.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect. There were a couple of equivalently correct answers so I chose the other based on timestamp, but nothing wrong with this one either.