string_view<uint8_t>
I have a big vector of bytes, and I want to take a part of it, interpret these bytes as ASCII characters written in hexadecimal system and print this substring on the screen. I don't need a copy, so I want to use std::basic_string_view<uint8_t>. The code below will cause the compilation error ("no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream'} and 'std::basic_string_view'").
What is the best way to print the substring without any copies?
(In the example below I wan't to have "cde" on the screen)
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<uint8_t> v { 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66 };
    std::basic_string_view<uint8_t> b { v.begin() + 2, v.begin() + 5 };
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


Please provide [mcve] since this fails to compile for more then one reason. I've got this (after fixing many things): https://godbolt.org/z/nnfEd5h7o

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator_ltlt

Maybe it's clear for others, but not to me. You want the hex bytes displayed as a hex string, meaning you want uint8_t 0x61 to become "0x61" (basically a number to string conversion) or you want the hex equivalent of an ASCII string (meaning you want uint8_t 0x61 to become "a")?

@TheNomad I wan't uint8_t 0x61 to become "a"

std::cout is a std::basic_ostream<char> which means that only an overload of the stream operator for std::string_view<char> is defined, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator_ltlt.
If you want to print a std::basic_string_view you need to only pass it to a stream with the same character type or you'll have to print the string with your own function.
If you want to create a std::string_view you can either change the type of the std::vector to std::vector<char> or cast to char when creating the string_view:
std::basic_string_view<char> sv{ reinterpret_cast<char*>(v.data()) + begin, end - begin };
std::cout << sv << std::endl;    


reinterpret_cast always makes me nervous. It will work, but AFAIK this is UB.

@MarekR You're allowed to reinterpret any type as char.

char, unsigned char, or std::byte have special dispensation.

@AlanBirtles Thank you for your answer. Yes, the easiest way is to change type of the std::vector to char, but I can't change it now. I think the solution with 'reinterpret_cast' is a good option. But can I overload operator << for unsigned char to use it with std::basic_string_view<uint8_t> directly?

@razenkovv it's not generally a great idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443172/is-it-allowed-to-overload-operator-for-a-standard-library-type-and-a-built-in-t
